# custom rails validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not sure what the best way to implement this is--basically I would like to check if my :start_amount field of my model is within a range from 0 to user.amount.
I'm not sure how to say 'user.amount' since it's not static like the other validations.

(for reference I did
`validates_numericality_of :start_amount, :allow_nil => false, :greater_than => 0`

and then did this in the same model:

```
def validates
    self.errors.add(:start_amount, "is out of range") unless self.amount_in_allowed_range
  end

  def amount_in_allowed_range
    start_amount <= user.amount
  end
```

It's pretty simple so I didn't think creating another class for the validation was needed (maybe that's the only way it works?) 
It was working ok except when I left `start_amount` blank, in which case it was comparing nil `<= user.amount` and gave an error (which I think is weird, since it should be checking for that in the validates_numericality_of--but I guess the custom validation runs first).  Then I changed it to the above with `:allow_nil => false` and also set it as `:null => false, :default => 0` in my migrations.  now it just doesn't seem to check at all? or it's permanently 0, and thus always passes validation...)

I'm really new to rails and would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
validates_numericality_of :start_amount
validate :amount_in_allowed_range

def amount_in_allowed_range
   self.errors.add(:start_amount, "is out of range") unless start_amount <= self.user.amount
end
```

That should work if your current model has a `belongs_to` relationship to user.  Note that custom validation methods are declared singular (`validate` instead of `validates`).  Also, `allow_nil` is false by default.  And I am not sure why `:default => 0` was set in your routes?  Did you mean migrations?  Please give a bit more detail about what your setup looks like.  What sort of error were you getting when `nil` was compared to `user.amount`?

Comment: Ah yes I meant migrations, not routes for :default =>0 (corrected it).  When I use what you suggested there is no change--it's as if there is no custom validation.  I used def validates because it seemed like that was the default custom validation name.  How could you a raise a custom error without the .errors.add? The error was a NoMethodError when nil was compared to user.amount.

Comment: You are right, you need `errors.add` and it needed to be conditional.  I edited the method to reflect it